# Integrate Shoes into Aptana Studio RadRails

Tags: ruby, ide, aptana, shoes

How can I run my [Carpet](http://shoooes.net) applications directly from Aptana Studio with RadRails? Setting the shoes.exe as VM/Interpreter won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the file in a Ruby project, you can do the following:

1. Go to Run -> External Tools -> External Tools...
2. Create a new tool, name it something (like, say, "Shoes")
3. Set Location to the Shoes binary, for example, on my system it's `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Shoes\0.r1134\shoes.exe`
4. Set Working Directory to `${workspace_loc}${project_loc}`  (You can change this to fit your needs, but I'd assume the project's base directory is as good a place as any to set as the working directory)
5. Set Arguments to `"${workspace_loc}${resource_path}"`  The double quotes **should** be included, otherwise any spaces in your path will muck things up.

That's it.  Now you can run it by going to Run -> External Tools -> Shoes, or using the External Tools icon on the toolbar.

Comment: Thanks Pesto. Just one correction, 4. should read: ${workspace_loc}${project_path}

Comment: I just tried to do this but under Run there is no "External Tools" under the Run tab or the options menu. I'm running Aptana Studio 3.4.2 on OS X Mavericks...