# Run Shoes gui app in IDE

Tags: ruby, ide, shoes

Is there any way to write Shoes application using IDE (NetBeans for example)?
I hadn't found this solution and I don't like running Shoes app, selecting files, run.

I'm sure code for packing Shoes and IDE code will be different (I hope in require directives only), but I'm intresting in **possibility**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738092/integrate-shoes-into-aptana-studio-radrails) for how to accomplish it in RadRails/Eclipse.  I'm sure it's equally possible in NetBeans, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: He-he, thanks, Strangely I don't think about running shoes executable :) I left NetBeans (I don't find feature like "External tool"), choosed Notepad++, bind running .bat file to key. And life becomes better :).