# Integrating Shoes with latest version of Aptana

Tags: ruby, user-interface, aptana, shoes

I found a previous question about [integrating Shoes with Aptana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738092/integrate-shoes-into-aptana-studio-radrails) for writing GUIs with ruby. I'm totally stoked, man. I've been learning the language for a while, and am finally comfortable writing code in it. Now if I could just get the darn toolkit working with the latest version of aptana!

[edit for clarity] I need to know how to run a program using Shoes from Aptana Studio.

Comment: Aptana is an IDE,it cant wear shoes

Comment: not a real question?  I have the same not real question...

Comment: The moderator should be closed for not being a real moderator...